# Migrate rgb values to HSL and hex in MYSQL db

Tags: mysql, colors, rgb

I have a mysql db that looks like this

```
target_color       
'rgb(200,200,200)'
'rgb(190,29,209)'
```

and I need to produce a db that looks like this

```
target_hue   ~   target_saturation  ~ target_lightness   ~   hex_value
10          ~    40        ~         40           ~         a567ff
```

The main problem I am running into is the parsing of the `rgb(x,y,z)` to extract the values. I thought that a regex would do the trick, but they are not supported in mysql...tried `substrint()` and `substring_index()` as well, but got totally tangled...

Comment: You're probably going to need a program to perform that conversion.  Though it might make your life easier if you simply had a target_color_r, target_color_g, and a target_color_b.

Comment: Hey! Thanks Neil, I know i screwed up, I am just trying to find my way out of it as soon as possible...

Comment: Don't take it that way.  I don't mean to tell you how you should have done it so much as finding a quick solution.  Parsing rgb(###,###,###) should be easier than parsing and converting values to their respective hue, saturation, and lightness.

Comment: Hey Neil, sorry if it came out rude, I didn't mean to be so. Was able to change my table and I am now writing clean h s and l to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to pull out the individual integer values between the commas.

```
SET @rgb := 'rgb(190,29,209)' ;

SELECT @rgb
     , @rgbv := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgb,'rgb(',-1),')',1) AS `@rgbv`
     , @v1 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',1)                             AS `@v1`
     , @v2 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',2),',',-1)     AS `@v2`
     , @v3 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',3),',',-1)     AS `@v3`
     , 0 + @v1  AS R
     , 0 + @v2  AS G
     , 0 + @v3  AS B
```

The last three columns in the SELECT list demonstrate that the user variables can be used in other (subsequent) expressions, in this case, adding them to an integer value of 0 to return them as integers.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't provide `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions. Those would be convenient, so you could get a value for Hue with an expression like this:

```
GREATEST(0+@v1,0+@v2,0+@v3) - LEAST(0+@v1,0+@v2,0+@v3)
```

You can "roll your own" greatest and least functions for the three values:

```
IF(0+@v1>0+@v2
  ,IF(0+@v1>0+@v3,0+@v1,IF(0+@v2>0+@v3,0+@v2,0+@v3))
  ,IF(0+@v2>0+@v3,0+@v2,0+@v3)
  ) AS `max(R,G,B)`

IF(0+@v1<0+@v2
  ,IF(0+@v1<0+@v3,0+@v1,IF(0+@v2<0+@v3,0+@v2,0+@v3))
  ,IF(0+@v2<0+@v3,0+@v2,0+@v3)
  ) AS `min(R,G,B)`
```

---

From a table containing a column named rgb, a query might look like this:

```
SELECT s.R
     , s.G
     , s.B
     , IF(s.R>s.G,IF(s.R>s.B,s.R,s.B),IF(s.G>s.B,s.G,s.B)) AS `max(R,G,B)`
     , IF(s.R<s.G,IF(s.R<s.B,s.R,s.B),IF(s.G<s.B,s.G,s.B)) AS `min(R,G,B)`
  FROM (
         SELECT t.rgb
              , @rgbv := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.rgb,'rgb(',-1),')',1) AS `@rgbv`
              , @v1 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',1)                              AS `@v1`
              , @v2 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',2),',',-1)      AS `@v2`
              , @v3 := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@rgbv,',',3),',',-1)      AS `@v3`
              , 0 + @v1  AS v1
              , 0 + @v2  AS v2
              , 0 + @v3  AS v3
           FROM mytable t
       ) s
```

Comment: Awesome! HSL from here is extremely easy!

Answer (score 0):

Given the field that contains `'rgb(190,29,209)'` is called `rgb` , then you can extract those three values with this sql:

```
select 
   substring(rgb, locate('(',rgb)+1,locate(',',rgb) -1 - locate('(',rgb)) as red,
   substring(substring_index(rgb,',',2) , locate(',',rgb)+1) as green,
   substring(rgb, locate(',',rgb, locate(',',rgb)+1 )+1 , locate(')',rgb) 
                   -1 - locate(',',rgb, locate(',',rgb)+1 )) as blue
```

that would output this result set:

```
red  green  blue
190  29     209
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to convert csv rgb values directly into hex.

```
UPDATE table1 ami
JOIN 
(
SELECT id, value 
, SUBSTRING(value, 1, LOCATE(',', value)-1) as R
, SUBSTRING(value, LOCATE(',', value)+1, LOCATE(',', value, LOCATE(',', value)+1) - LOCATE(',', value) - 1) G
, SUBSTRING(value, LOCATE(',', value, LOCATE(',', value)+1)+1) B
from table1 ai
where locate(',', value) > 0
) tbl ON ami.id = tbl.id
SET ami.value = CONCAT(
 LPAD(CONV(tbl.R, 10, 16),2,'0') 
, LPAD(CONV(tbl.G, 10, 16),2,'0')
, LPAD(CONV(tbl.B, 10, 16),2,'0'));
```

Obviously change the table names :)
Hope this helps someone else.